# Install UWP without developer-mode and sideloading

Tags: uwp, installation, windows-10-universal

In the win10 UWP with non-store, install app should open developer-mode or side-loading mode.

However, My company have high security level. I can't change any setting for target notebooks. Specifically, these notebooks even not "for developers" in update&security.

My job is create an auto wifi-selector app with UWP for company. So, this app will not upload to Microsoft store.

Has any way to install UWP app to hundreds of notebooks with not open developer-mode or side-loading mode.

Comment: So not even Private Store is allowed? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/distribute-lob-apps-to-enterprises

Answer (score 1):

> Install UWP without developer-mode and sideloading

If you want install app within **non-store**, **non-sideload**, **no-developer mode**, the better way is that use **line-of-business apps**. However even using this way you cannot completely isolate Microsoft store

Your company or school can make line-of-business (LOB) applications available through Microsoft Store for Business or Microsoft Store for Education. These apps are custom to your school or organization – they might be **internal** apps, or apps specific to your school, business, or industry. For detail steps please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/working-with-line-of-business-apps#a-href-idadding-lob-appsaadding-lob-apps-to-your-private-store).

Distribute apps to your employees from Microsoft Store for Business and Microsoft Store for Education. You can assign apps to employees, or let employees install them from your private store. Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/distribute-apps-to-your-employees-microsoft-store-for-business).