# Install UWP on devices without developer mode remotely (No developer mode, No internet/store access, Deploy via LAN)

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

There is a requirement for an enterprise UWP application that needs to work on Windows 10 without turning on the developer mode.

Queries:

- Is there a way to way to sideload or install UWP apps ***without* turning on the developer mode**?
- Would it be possible to remote Install UWPs? (Deploy to devices in local LAN) Any enterprise solutions?
- What are the considerations and procedures?

In case there is no way for above method, Can we instead do the following:

1. Enable developer mode
2. Install the UWP
3. Disable developer mode
4. Use UWP (Do all UWP devices access features work)

Found something close but not the preferred way: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36429885-86f3-49b1-b774-afef657250b6/publish-uwp-app-out-side-store-with-certification-issue?forum=windowsstore

[Edit]: Doesn't fit my requirement but for others looking: Line of Business (LOB) apps or private store are possible options as mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55699838/10224384).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to sideload the app if the app is signed with a certificate the device trusts. To do this:

1. Assign certificate to application
2. Sign application
3. Enable unlock policy for sideloading for end users
4. Import certificate to end user devices
5. Install the app via powershell

3, 4, 5 should be possible via system-wide policies so there will be no need to deal with each device